# Working with React useEffect & local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I've never worked with local storage in combination with React.

**My goal is simple:** When users complete a test, localstorage should store a value saying they've completed the test. If the completedTest State is true, show a ShowResultsComponent.

Showhow I feel as if I'm going about this the incorrect way.

```
// I'd like localStorage.complete to start as false. 

const [completedTest, setCompletedTest] = useState(localStorage.complete);

useEffect(() => {
localStorage.getItem('complete');
}, []);

const completeTest = () => {
localStorage.setItem('complete', true);
}


{completedTest ? 
<ShowResultsComponent />
: null }
```

Comment: maybe this will help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660153/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-value-changes-in-react

Comment: when you set the complete true in localstorage, change your state as well

Comment: @NishargShah is that not accomplished with: const [completedTest, setCompletedTest] = useState(localStorage.complete);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the state of `completedTest` in the `useEffect()` hook. Also, when conditionally rendering, you should use an empty React fragment `<></>` instead of `null`.

Example:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const [completedTest, setCompletedTest] = useState(localStorage.complete);

  useEffect(() => {
    const c = localStorage.getItem("complete");
    setCompletedTest(c);
  }, []);

  const completeTest = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("complete", true);
    setCompletedTest(true);
  };

  return <div>{completedTest ? <div>render this if completed</div> : <></>}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, no need to listen the `localstorage`.

```js
const isCompleted = localStorage.getItem("complete") === 'true';
const [completedTest, setCompletedTest] = useState(isCompleted);

const completeTest = () => {
   localStorage.setItem('complete', true);
   setCompletedTest(true)
}


return completedTest ? <ShowResultsComponent />: null;
```

Comment: On a page refresh, wouldn't completedTest return to false? (That's my issue)

Comment: Ohk, see updated one

Comment: Sweet let me give this a try

Comment: For some reason it seems that completedTest is undefined on first load. How could I make completedTest be set to false on first load?

Comment: on firstLoad it will be `false` (check new code - refresh the page), I am checking localstorage getItem to be 'true' so if localstorage doesn't have `complete` item then it will return undefined and I am checking that with 'true' so it will return false