# Using a localStorage value as a useEffect dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use localstorage value of `benchmarkActiveTab` in the dependency array? The value is changing in the localstorage but the `useEffect` isn't running when the value changes

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(
  localStorage.getItem("benchmarkActiveTab") || 0
)

useEffect(() => {
  async function getBenchmarkTimes() {
    // this function doesn't run
  }
  getBenchmarkTimes()
}, [activeTab])
```

I tried to make the `useEffect` run when the `localStorage.getItem('benchmarkActiveTab')` changes, but the useEffect doesn't run.

Comment: Where are you setting this value in `localStorage`?

Comment: @Unmitigated In a different component

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

Comment: localStorage is a round-about way share data between components, there are many more effective strategies to be employed before resorting to it, from passing state down, shared state in a parent, or using a context. As for your dependency, the state initializer only runs on first mount, so `activeTab` will never change based on what code you've shown.

Comment: @DanielA.White it looks like that hook has the same limitations, it won't update on localStorage change, just on remount of the component. However [this hook](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage) includes a listener for change.

Comment: duplicate [How to listen to localstorage value changes in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660153/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-value-changes-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to `storage` event

```js
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(
  localStorage.getItem("benchmarkActiveTab") || 0
)

useEffect(() => {
  const OnStorageEvent = async () => {
    const value = localStorage.getItem('benchmarkActiveTab') || 0

    if (activeTab !== value) {
      // value change
      setActiveTab(value)

      // Run getBenchmarkTimes here
      // use value instead of activeTab here because react update after re render
    }
  }

  addEventListener("storage", OnStorageEvent)

  return () => removeEventListener("storage", OnStorageEvent)
}, [activeTab])
```

Comment: You don't need `activeTab` as a dependency then, just run once on mount

Comment: Also this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660153/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-value-changes-in-react)

Comment: @pilchard It is used to compare if the value changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the state `activeTab` is only set once during the initial render. It never changes again. So the effect depends on it will never run again either.

You can use [`useSyncExternalStore`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore) hook. This hook accept two kind of params: `subscribe` and `getSnapshot`. Every time `subscribe` call the callback, React calls `getSnapshot` and gets a fresh snapshot. If the snapshot changes (when result from `Object.is` is false), React rerender the component.

```js
function useLocalStorageValue(key, interval = 100) {
  // run callback intervally
  const subscribe = (callback) => {
    let enabled = true;
    const fn = () =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        callback();
        if (enabled) fn();
      }, interval);
    fn();
    return () => {
      enabled = false;
    };
  };

  // get value from localstorage
  const getSnapShot = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  };

  return useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapShot, getSnapShot);
}
```

See full example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/uselocalstoragevalue-dg10kz?file=/src/App.js:70-566).