# How to Stop infinite loop while fetching data from localStorage in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, infinite-loop

When I'm fetching data from localStorage in useEffect Hook and passing dependency [] blank. It fetchs data well but it not fetch new data. To fetch that, it requires refresh the page. And when I pass dependency [data] (fetched data state) it starts infinite loop.

This is my actual code. I have passed [data] dependency in useEffect to fetch when new data added. But it started infinite loop.

```
const LocalStorage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [city, setCity] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(id, name, city);

    const userInput = [...data, { id: id, name: name, city: city }];
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userInput));

    setId("");
    setName("");
    setCity("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedData = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const dataObject = JSON.parse(fetchedData);
    setData(dataObject);
  }, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect, you're modifying and depending on data in the same useEffect(). This causes an infinite loop. I believe what you want to do is either listen to changes in localStorage or only call setData in handleSubmit.

For example:

```
const LocalStorage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [city, setCity] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(id, name, city);

    const userInput = [...data, { id: id, name: name, city: city }];
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userInput));
    setData(userInput);

    setId("");
    setName("");
    setCity("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
  }, [data]);
};
```

Here's how you listen to localStorage:
[How to listen to localstorage value changes in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660153/how-to-listen-to-localstorage-value-changes-in-react)